# How to optimize scoring of elastic search results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "firstname": "john martin"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "lastname": "john martin"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "firstname": "john martin"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "lastname": "john martin"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "state": "61"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is giving me suitable results that is all the people with have john OR martin in their first or last names. 
Now suppose I have below results:

- john dcruise
- john shane
- shane martin
- martin json
- john martin
- johnson cage

What I want is to score **john martin** higher than other results as it is an exact match. 
Is there any other filter which I can use to optimize my search results.

Please suggest any specific link where I can read about scoring my results and learn more about it.

May be I have not done my homework very well but I am beginner and trying to know more about relevance scoring and in huge requirement of applying what I have stated above.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you have two `lastname` match query?

Comment: I guess second one should be `firstname`

Comment: I get `john martin` result as a first easily when I implement your example like my gist https://gist.github.com/hkulekci/d3c399b9430cc489dfe56bbced37a894 Why do you want to `match` and `match_phrase_prefix` with together?

Comment: Thanks @hkulekci That was the problem with my code I was matching last name in match filter. Secondly I am using match and match_phrase_prefix because I want to get john martin  in case I search 'john martin' or 'joh'. Thanks!!

Comment: should I delete my question. As it is no more relevant.